# MongoError: BSONObj exceeded maximum nested object depth: 200

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Nodejs express server is up and running for 2 days then suddenly The server encountered an internal error in one of the HTTP requests which executing aggregation pipeline on mongodb.

Here is the error:

> MongoError: BSONObj exceeded maximum nested object depth: 200

This will be resolve after restarting the server but will occur again after period of time (currently 2 days).

Here is the aggregation code:

```
let aggregate = messages.aggregate() .match(matchFilter) .group({ _id: '$_id', lastSentMessageDateTime: { $first: '$lastSentMessageDateTime' }, eta: { $first: '$eta' } }) .addFields({ virtualEta: { $cond: { if: { $ifNull: ["$eta", false] }, then: '$eta', else: new Date('1/1/2030') } } });
```

How could this aggregation pipeline result in objects with more than 200 nested level?

This code will work regularly but not after period of server up time (currently after 2 days the error will come up).

So there are no nested objects in the result documents. So what does this error specifically mean?

Comment: This appears to be a read-only operation.  What is done with the `aggregate` variable after this call?

Comment: using it as param in aggregate-paginate package 
aggregatePaginate(aggregate, {
        page: 1,
        limit: 25,
        sort: {
            [virtualEtaField]: 1
        },
        allowDiskUse: true
    });
@Joe